# Conditional Expectation Problem With Noise

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I was given the following problem:
let $X,N\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and let $A$ equal $1$ w.p $p$ and $0$ w.p $1-p$. Also, let $X,N,A$ be independent.
Define $Y=AX+N$. Find $\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y)$.

My idea was to use the 'nested conditioning' property $\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y)\overset{\text{a.s}}{=}\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y,A)\mid Y]$.
I defined $Z=Y\mid A$ (which is likely at the very least a horrible abuse of notation).
$(X,Z)$ is undoubtedly a Gaussian vector (i.e jointly Gaussian) as a linear transformation of $(X,Y)$. Noting $Z\sim\mathcal{N}(0,A^2+1)$ we have $\mathbb{E}(X\mid Z)=\frac{\text{cov}(X,Z)}{\text{var}(Z)}Z=\frac{A}{A^2+1}Z$ , where I found $\text{cov}(X,Z)$ via the covariance matrix of $(X,Z)$.

I figure $\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y,A)=\mathbb{E}(X\mid Z)$, so substituting into the nesting property yields $$\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y)=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(X\mid Z)\mid Y]=\mathbb{E}\left( \frac{A}{A^2+1}Y\mid Y\right) =Y\mathbb{E}\left( \frac{A}{A^2+1}\mid Y\right)$$
And now I'm lost.

I'd like to know whether I've made any forbidden manipulations, and of course, I'd like a hint to help me out!

Comment: The assumption $\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid Y,A\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid Z\right)$ is wrong.

Comment: Did you actually get a solution from the accepted answer? If you did, what do you think E(X|Y) is, in the end?

Comment: Calculating just now, I got $\frac{p}{2}(X+N)$

Comment: This surprises me. I would be curious to see a proof of this identity.

Comment: I learned that for a Gaussian vector $(X,Z)^T$ with zero mean, $E(X\mid Z)=\frac{\text{cov}(X,Z)}{\text{var}Z}Z$

Comment: True, but how is this relevant? Here, Y is not normal.

Comment: Using the answer I received here, it remains only to calculate $E(X\mid X+N)$ and $(X,X+N)^T$ is a Gaussian vector.

Comment: The only problem is that said answer is (i) unmotivated and (ii) deeply wrong. Sorry. (Or, do you actually understand it? To begin with, how would you explain the first equal sign, which states that a (nondegenerate) random variable equals a number?)

Comment: By the way, were you graded on this homework? And did you receive a correction sheet?

Comment: In one of my comments to the answer I assumed the author forgot to condition the outer expectation on $A$ in the second term. I think it makes sense if one adds that conditioning. My homework answer was accepted.

Comment: Condition on $Y$, excuse me.

Comment: Just to be sure, you answered that $E(X\mid AX+N)=\frac12p(X+N)$ and this was accepted as the correct answer?

Comment: Yep. I'm not certain it was one of the questions checked (not all questions in HW assignments here are checked)

Comment: Does what I mentioned about the forgotten outer conditioning on $Y$ not resolve the problem?

Comment: How convenient. If ever this question was "checked", then the person who checked it is a fraud.

Comment: No, you are very far from having solved the question. A sure sign that your answer is wrong is the fact that $\frac12p(X+N)$ is not even measurable with respect to $AX+N$.

Comment: I blindly used $E(X\mid Y)=E(X\mid Y,A)\mid Y)$ and I don't understand what is wrong. Can you explain what you said about the measurability?

Comment: "Blindly": OK, so what do you think E(X|Y,A) is? "Measurability": By definition, for every (U,V), there exists some measurable function a such that E(U|V)=a(V).

Comment: So because the answer is not a funtion of $AX+N$ it is ruled out immediately, right?

Comment: Right. Which begs the question: what is *your* definition of conditional expectation, in general?

Comment: The extension of the $L^2$ projection on the $\sigma (V)$ measurable subspace.

Comment: Then you did not check that the proposed solution had the projection property (with no extension needed since everybody is square integrable here)...

Comment: I really didn't do anything smart at all.

Comment: By the way, is $E(X\mid Y, A)=\frac{A}{A+1}(AX+N)$ correct?

Comment: By the way, why don't you go back to the definitions and check whether this is or is not E(X|Y,A)?

Comment: Okay. I'll do that when I wake up and I'll post what I do. Thank you very much for the careful attention. I really appreciate it.

Comment: You have loooong sleeps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**PS written some months later:** This answer has some issues, which I will soon address in some edits.  See the comments below. **End of PS.**

$\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb E}$
$$
\E(X\mid Y)=\E(\E(X\mid Y,A)) = \E\left.\begin{cases} \E(X\mid X+N) & \text{if }A=1 \\ 0 & \text{if }A=0 \end{cases}\right\} = p\E(X\mid X+N).
$$
Whether all of these equalities are correct I leave for the moment as an exercise, which I haven't yet completely done myself.  The last conditional expected value can be found with formulas found in all the books, which it appears you probably know.

Comment: I don't understand why, in the third equality, the expectation becomes conditioned on $X+Y$

Comment: I guess it was a typo and $X+N$ should replace $X+Y$. Also, could it be you forgot to condition on $A$ in the second term? At any rate, thank you very much! I'm hoping you might take a look and tell me if any part of my (futile) attempt is actually wrong - I want to make sure I haven't done anything wrong.

Comment: Correction: condition on *$Y$* in the second term. For now I don't understand the calculation :\

Comment: Assuming the typos I mentioned, I got it. Thanks again.

Comment: I think I understand none of the three equal signs in this answer.

Comment: @Did : The first one is just the law of total expectation.  A random variable $\operatorname{E}(W\mid A)$ is equal to $\operatorname{E}(W\mid A=1)$ with probability $p$ and to $\operatorname{E}(W\mid A=0)$ with probability $1-p$, so its expected value is $p\operatorname{E}(W\mid A=1)+(1-p)\operatorname{E}(W\mid A=0)$.  If $\operatorname{E}(W\mid A=0)$ happens to be $0$ then the expected value of $\operatorname{E}(W\mid A)$ is $p\operatorname{E}(W\mid A=1)$. And in the case of this question $\operatorname{E}(X\mid AX+N, A=1)$ is $\operatorname{E}(X\mid X+N)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: No. Already the first one is odd since (X∣Y) is a (nonconstant) random variable while ((X∣Y,A)) is a number. (But it is cool to get a reaction six months later...)

Comment: But $\operatorname{E}(X\mid Y,A)$ is not a number, since $Y$ and $A$ are random variables. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: OK, two things: (1) Use `@`. (2) Yes E(X|Y,A) is a random variable, not a constant (in general), and E(E(X|Y,A)) is its expectation, that is, **a number** (always). And your answer uses E(E(X|Y,A)), not simply E(X|Y,A). (And addressing what I did not write is a good way to fail to address what I actually wrote.)

Comment: @Did : OK, I'm going to delete the answer and then revise it and then restore it.

Comment: OK. One remaining option is to revamp the answer into a perfect solution, this way everybody will be happy.